# Getting percentiles by row in Python/Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a Dataframe for which I want percentiles row-wise. Although, the documentation of pandas.quantile() [0.14] method *does* include an *axis=* argument, the result is not as expected:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(6, 3), columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
          a         b         c
0 -0.815200  0.137148 -1.378515
1  0.106762  0.689793 -0.261648
2 -1.013495  0.807520  1.211062
3 -0.182480  1.082589 -0.825990
4  0.480081  0.864027 -0.192584
5 -2.081455 -0.003881 -1.003602

In [6]: df.quantile(0.95,axis=1)
Out[6]: 
a    0.386751
b    1.027949
c    0.860151
dtype: float64

In [7]: df.quantile(0.95,axis=0)
Out[7]: 
a    0.386751
b    1.027949
c    0.860151
dtype: float64
```

Just wanted to get it to your attention. Also, wanted to know what would be the most efficient workaround for this.

Comment: I spent 15 min on 2 versions of pandas (.14 and .15) and I can't recreate this on windows with python 2.7.

Comment: I can't recreate this with pandas 0.14.1 on linux with python 3 either

Comment: Cannot reproduce using Pandas .14.1 on Mac with Python 2.7

Comment: That sounds strange, should I have a go at reinstalling pandas? FYI i'm using anaconda python distribution on Mac where I upgraded pandas to 0.14.0.

Answer (score 2):

Could not reproduce this as well.
But `df.T.quantile(0.95)` should work.